# Need advice for Azure functions oauth2 authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I am building product using Azure Functions (nodeJS).

I have azure function, which will act as `oauth2` authentication server following the `oauth2` standards and will be used by all other function projects.

It will be used by Azure functions part of the same product.

I am wondering can I use `"authLevel": "function"` to make sure it is call is from "allowed client"?

Or I have to implement client verification functionality as per `oauth2`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `"authLevel": "function"`, it just means the function requires the function key to auth, the function url will be like `https://joyfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=w9xxxxxVcfxRQ==`, the `code` is the function key, it will be exposed in the url, anyone got it will be able to access the function.

In your case, I recommend you to secure the function with Azure AD, by default, it just allows the users in your AAD tenant to access the function, you can also set it to let the users with the specific role to access the function, follow this blog https://adatum.no/azure/azure-ad-authentication-in-azure-functions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have the users stored in cosmosDB not as azure AD (pricing requirement). The auth server will not be used by 3rd parties as authorization provider. And by the OAUTH2.0 standrads it has to check the client credentials when the client is issued a secret (which is not, since it is a web client). It just seems that in this case I have 1 endpoint to protect (called only by internal code).